# VBA - My code does either coloring or changing form but "forgets" to do both

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm having some issue with something I've been trying to do on excel : I've written something -bit of me, bit of what I could find on the internet hen I was stuck- that creates a chart (scatter) and should show points that have different colors, depending on values in a column just next to the y values and have different Markerstyle depending on the values in a column a bit further away. However, it only remembers to do one of the things I asked.

```
Sub Figure2()
'
' Figure2 Macro
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim u As Integer
Dim NameRng As String
Dim CountsRng As Range
Dim xRng As Range
Dim x As Long

LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ColumnCount = LastColumn
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' Debug.Print ("Last Column: " & LastColumn & " Count: " & ColumnCount & "   LastRow: " & LastRow)

' Création du graph
Range("A1:B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Feuil3!$A$1:$B$" & LastRow)
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete

' For colors
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim pt As Point
Dim p As Long
Dim Vals$, lTrim#, rTrim#
Dim valRange As Range, cl As Range
Dim myColor As Long
Dim srsi As Series
Dim pti As Point
Dim pi As Long

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

lTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",", InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",") - 1, vbBinaryCompare) + 1
rTrim = InStrRev(srs.Formula, ",")
Vals = Mid(srs.Formula, lTrim, rTrim - lTrim)
Set valRange = Range(Vals)

For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
    Set pt = srs.Points(p)
' where to go for values
    Set cl = valRange(p).Offset(0, 1)
    With pt.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
       Select Case LCase(cl)
' changing color for the one next to its cell
            Case "red"
                myColor = RGB(217, 0, 18)
            Case "blue"
                myColor = RGB(77, 63, 255)
            Case "green"
                myColor = RGB(28, 210, 32)
        End Select
    End With
    Next
' Everything working so far, with the graph and the right colors
```

Now this is where I'm having trouble as when I write what follows, excel forgets about the colors it just put and just remembers to change the form

```
' Changing MarkerStyle

    Set srsi = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    For pi = 1 To srsi.Points.Count
    Set pti = srsi.Points(pi)
' where to go for values
```

This time it should go to another column as the one before

```
    Set cli = valRange(pi).Offset(0, 3)
    With pti.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
       Select Case LCase(cli)
' going three columns from here
            Case "boxer"
' changing
                 pti.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
                 pti.MarkerSize = 7
            Case ""
                 pti.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
                 pti.MarkerSize = 6
            Case "ea390/398"
                 pti.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleTriangle
                 pti.MarkerSize = 6
        End Select
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

At the end, I have a plot with only red points and different forms.
Do you know where I went wrong ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't see where your code *uses* the variable `myColor`. I see values assigned to that variable in the case statements, but once assigned they seem to be just overwritten before use in the next pass through the loop.

Comment: @John Coleman. I am not sure I understand, should I have added something to "tell" the values to stick with the colors ? In the first loop for p=1 to srs.Points.Count, I use 'myColor'. But I don't understand how it's overwritten since the two loops are distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop, you are assigning values to the variable `myColor` but then are not doing anything with that variable. You need to assign the color to the point.

Replace

```
With pt.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
       Select Case LCase(cl)
' changing color for the one next to its cell
            Case "red"
                myColor = RGB(217, 0, 18)
            Case "blue"
                myColor = RGB(77, 63, 255)
            Case "green"
                myColor = RGB(28, 210, 32)
        End Select
    End With
```

with

```
With pt.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
       Select Case LCase(cl)
' changing color for the one next to its cell
            Case "red"
                myColor = RGB(217, 0, 18)
            Case "blue"
                myColor = RGB(77, 63, 255)
            Case "green"
                myColor = RGB(28, 210, 32)
        End Select
        .BackColor.RGB = myColor
        .ForeColor.RGB = myColor
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much it solved it perfectly ! Have a nice day !